# Running PHP runs as root instead of logged in user

Tags: command-line, php, environment-variables, php-cli

I have a little development environment with a PHP script that only contains the following:

whichuser.php

```
<?php var_dump( exec('whoami') ); ?>
```

When I try to execute this "script" via CLI the following happens:

```
ubuntu@dev:/var/www/html/$ php whichuser.php
string(4) "root"
```

However, if I run the command as follows, I get a different output:

```
ubuntu@dev:/var/www/html/$ /usr/bin/php whichuser.php
string(6) "ubuntu"
```

I image this is an issue with my PATH settings, they look as follows:

```
ubuntu@dev:/var/www/html/$  echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/bin/php:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/bin/php
```

It might look a bit weird as I have been trying to solve this issue myself.

Can anyone provide some suggestions?

If the question isn't clear, I am trying to make the CLI command `php` run as the current logged in user, as it should be.

**EDIT 1**

I have run the below command as per your suggestions:

```
ubuntu@dev:/var/www/html/$  ls -l $( type -a -p php)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Jan 22 06:57 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php
```

I am not sure if this symlink is the issue. Does this provide insight in to what is going on?

**EDIT 2**

I have also run the below command due to another suggestion:

```
ubuntu@dev:/var/www/html/$  type -a php
php is aliased to `sudo php'
php is /usr/bin/php
```

Looks like that aliased line is the culprit. I take it its not supposed to be that way?

**EDIT 3 - Solution**

Thanks to the tip provided by @wjandrea, I was able to find the the bash alias file at `/home/ubuntu/.bash_aliases`.

In it was the alias directive which I removed. I then relogged and `php` was working as expected.

I also removed the line `/usr/bin/php` from my `PATH` variable as it should not be there.

@wjandrea, if you want to answer the question properly, I will mark your response as the solution, giving you credit where it is due.

Comment: There is a difference between `php` and `/usr/bin/php`. Do `ls -l $( type -a -p php) /usr/bin/php`. Is one of them setUID `root`?

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of `type -a php`, plus what @waltinator mentioned.

Comment: `/usr/bin/php` shouldn't be in your PATH. The PATH should have directories, not files.

Comment: @waltinator I have edited my post with you request.

Comment: @wjandrea I also ran your command and I think it points to the issue, what can I do from here?

Comment: @PeterA Hey, I just gave you a hint, didn't figure it all out myself ;) You can post your own answer. Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `php` command was being aliased to `sudo php`.

I edited my `/home/ubuntu/.bash_aliases` file and removed the alias record.

Relogging after that resolved the issue.